# Trouble understanding these Haxe functions

Tags: ios, swift, haxe

I've been working on mimicking [this article](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-procedurally-generated-dungeon-cave-system--gamedev-10099) for my game. The article is about procedurally generating dungeon maps. I have successfully translated most of the Haxe code in this article. Most of the code I have translated, I have done so by mostly guessing and trial/error. I got to a part I don't fully understand:

> Now the goal is to connect each room so that we can walk through our dungeon and eventually reach an exit that leads to the next level. We can accomplish this by carving out corridors between the rooms.
>
> We will need to add a point variable to the code to keep track of the center of each room created. Whenever we create and place a room, we determine its center and connect it to the previous room's center.
>
> First, we'll implement the corridors:

```
private function hCorridor(x1:Int, x2:Int, y) {
    for (x in Std.int(Math.min(x1, x2))...Std.int(Math.max(x1, x2)) + 1) {
        // destory the tiles to "carve" out corridor
        map[x][y].parent.removeChild(map[x][y]);

        // place a new unblocked tile
        map[x][y] = new Tile(Tile.DARK_GROUND, false, false);

        // add tile as a new game object
        addChild(map[x][y]);

        // set the location of the tile appropriately
        map[x][y].setLoc(x, y);
    }
}

// create vertical corridor to connect rooms
private function vCorridor(y1:Int, y2:Int, x) {
    for (y in Std.int(Math.min(y1, y2))...Std.int(Math.max(y1, y2)) + 1) {
        // destroy the tiles to "carve" out corridor
        map[x][y].parent.removeChild(map[x][y]);

        // place a new unblocked tile
        map[x][y] = new Tile(Tile.DARK_GROUND, false, false);

        // add tile as a new game object
        addChild(map[x][y]);

        // set the location of the tile appropriately
        map[x][y].setLoc(x, y);
    }
}
```

> These functions act in nearly the same way, but one carves out horizontally and the other vertically.

[image: Image 1]

> We need three values in order to do this. For horizontal corridors we need the starting x value, the ending x value, and the current y value. For vertical corridors we need the starting and ending y values along with the current x value.
>
> Since we are moving from left to right we need the two corresponding x values, but only one y value since we won't be moving up or down. When we move vertically we will need the y values. In the for loop at the beginning of each function, we iterate from the starting value (x or y) to the ending value until we have carved out the entire corridor.

*Directly quoted from the article.*

I am trying to figure out how to write these same for-loops in Swift. I understand the function parameters and what the functions are supposed to do. I don't, however, understand what the swift equivalent for this line would be:

```
for (x in Std.int(Math.min(x1, x2))...Std.int(Math.max(x1, x2)) + 1)
```

All my attempts to translate it have failed. And to be honest, I am utterly confused and have no idea what this line is even doing.

Here is my current attempt:

```
func hCorridor(x1: Int, x2:Int, y: Int) {
    for x in x1...x2 {
        
    }
}
func vCorridor(y1: Int, y2:Int, x: Int) {
    for y in y1...y2 {
        
    }
}
```

(It doesn't work by the way.)

I can add my code so far, but I don't think dumping a ton of code into a question is a good idea.

Comment: Here's the issue with *your question* as I see it - if you are asking those of us with Swift experience (and I can include everything from COBOL/Fortran to C#) you really haven't explains the `haxe` piece of the logic (which spellcheck corrected to "hate"). Maybe I can help you - as I already said, I've used several languages over 40 years including SQL and proprietary ones - but I really cannot be sure what `for (x in Std.int(Math.min(x1, x2))...Std.int(Math.max(x1, x2)) + 1)` or `map[x][y].parent.removeChild(map[x][y])` or MOST OF ALL what `hCorridor(x1:Int, x2:Int, y)` is trying to do.

Comment: I just explained it in the question. At the bottom I *just* edited in the bit that I needed help with. Read the article I linked if you are confused about what the functions are for.

Comment: The question has been rewritten for better clarification and to better define my problem.

Comment: I removed my upvote based on your clarification. Links aren't helpful to anyone - sorry if you disagree with that - and as is it seems you are asking for help translating something that you haven't clearly defined. I sincerely hope you get the help you are asking for, but at this point it seems you are asking something this site isn't meant for.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. I quoted the part of the article that I am having trouble with, because the writer of the article is much better at explaining what I am trying to than I am. I singled my issue down to one the one line of code I am struggling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working off @JeffWard's answer (meaning I assume he understands Haxe), *a* Swift translation would be:

```
let min_x = min(x1, x2)
let max_x = max(x1, x2)
for _ in min_x...max_x {
}
```

A few more things:

- If you need to actually *use* the loop iterator, change the underscore to a variable.
- I'm not taking into account anything like type conversions or if `x1 == x2`. (But in the latter case, you should only pass through the loop twice.
- Assuming the above answer properly translates what you are trying to do, there's no need for `var`, `;`, or C style loops.
- I tried to emphasize that this is "a" Swift translation. I'm sure others can do better.

**EDIT:**

I immediately came up with what many would say *is* better or "Swiftier"! :-)

```
 for _ in min(x1,x2)...(max(x1,x2) {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! This does exactly what I needed. I apologize for the bad question that I wrote. I know the rules, I know how to write a good question and I was just being lazy. Also, it was late at night and I was having a hard time explaining what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't, however, understand what the swift equivalent for this line would be:

```
for (x in Std.int(Math.min(x1, x2))...Std.int(Math.max(x1, x2)) + 1)
```

This is called a [range iteration](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-for.html#range-iteration) in Haxe:

```
for (x in a...b) { }
```

It is equivalent to the following C-style for loop:

```
for (x=a; x<b; x++) { }
```

That loop isn't confusing, once you realize it's simply using a couple function calls as `a` and `b`. While I can't tell you the equivalent Swift code, I can tell you the pseudo-code of that loop:

```
var min_x = smaller_of(x1, x2);
var max_x = larger_of(x1, x2);
for (x = min_x; x<max_x + 1; x++) { }
```

Note: You can ignore the `Std.int()` as it's simply casting Float to Int.

You might find the [Haxe manual](https://haxe.org/manual) quite handy for any other questions you may have.

Answer (score 1):

The haxe for-loop you quoted iterates from the lowest x value to the highest. Math.min(x1,x2) will return the lowest value, so it can iterate from x1 to x2, or x2 to x1 depending on the values.

Swift seems to have [such comparison functions too](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538951-max), your current attempt doesn't seem to use it or replicate this logic.